# How to add a button to every list item in an unordered list?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple to-do list app and am unsure how to add a "delete" button beside each list item. My code so far is the following:

```js
document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var li = "<li>" + text + "</li>";
  document.getElementById("list").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', li);
  document.getElementById("input").value = ""; // clear the value
}
```

```html
<h1>To-Do List</h1>
<input type="text" id="input" />
<input type="button" value="Add Note" id="add" />
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in the same place where you add your `<li>` elements:

```
var li = "<li>" + text + "<button type='button'>delete</button></li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is use 
* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```
document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
    var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var li = `<li>${text} <input type="button" value="Delete"></li>`;
    document.getElementById("list").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', li);
    document.getElementById("input").value = ""; 
}
```